# How to add a NUL character separator using AWK in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, nul

I have a function which outputs some file paths, I need these paths are separated by NUL charachter instead of new line `\n` character. I tried following code:

```
function myfunc
{
  declare -a DUPS
  # some commands to fill DUPS with appropriate file/folder paths
  ( for i in "${DUPS[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done )|sort|uniq|awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\x00";} {print substr($0, index($0, $2))}'
}
```

But if I pipe its output to `hexdump` or `hd`, no NUL character is diplayed. It seems that NUL character is not included in the `awk` output:

```
myfunc | hd
```

Will print:

```
00000000  2f 70 61 74 68 2f 6e 75  6d 62 65 72 2f 6f 6e 65  |/path/number/one|
00000010  2f 2f 70 61 74 68 2f 6e  75 6d 62 65 72 2f 74 77  |//path/number/tw|
00000020  6f 2f 2f 70 61 74 68 2f  6e 75 6d 62 65 72 2f 74  |o//path/number/t|
00000030  68 72 65 65 2f                                    |hree/|
00000035
```

My `awk` version is:

```
~$ awk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040
```

Also any solution with other commands such as `sed` is acceptable for me.
**NOTE:** My question is not duplicate of [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133315), because it asks for a solution that works on different machines with different `awk`s. But I just need a solution that works on my own machine, so I could use any version of `awk` that could be installed on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What version of awk are you using?

Comment: @rici How I could find my `awk` version?

Comment: to install gawk, `sudo apt-get install gawk`. Or you can use the `printf` solution in my answer to get `mawk` to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Gnu Awk v4.0.1 works just fine with your original program, but all the other awks I have kicking around (`mawk`, `original-awk` and `busybox awk`) produce the same NUL-free output as you seem to be experiencing. It appears that with those awks, using either print or printf to print a string with embedded NULs causes the NUL to be treated as a string terminator.

However, `mawk` and `original-awk` will output a real NUL if you use `printf "%s",0;`. So if you are using one of those, you could set ORS to the empty string and add `{printf "%s", 0;}` to the end of your awk program. (You'd need other more invasive modifications if your awk program uses `next`).

I don't know any way to convince `busybox awk` to print a NUL byte, so if that is what you are using you might want to consider choosing a real awk.

Comment: I installed `Gnu Awk v4.0.1` and replaced `awk` with `gawk` in my code in the question. But the result is the same!

Comment: @PHPLearner: You got me. On my system, with gawk 4.0.1, it works perfectly. By the way, you can simplify considerably: `printf '%s\n' "${DUPS[@]}" | sort -u | awk ...`