# finding and deleting duplicate files (md5sum)

Tags: linux, cygwin

I have multiple directories containing multiple images, and some of these directories have duplicate images. I want to find all duplicate images within the same directory and delete them. Below is my code.

I'm having a problem with deleting the duplicate image. the code can identify duplicate files, but when it tries to delete it it shows this message"rm: cannot remove 'FILENAME': No such file or directory"

```
for dir in *; do
count=1
for file in $dir/*.*; do
     md5sum * | sort | awk 'BEGIN{lasthash = ""} $1 == lasthash {print $2} {lasthash = $1}' | xargs rm
     let count=count+1
done
done
```

Comment: Have you considered just using `fdupes` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The following excerpt from `xargs` manpage might explain what you see:

> ```
> find /tmp -name core -type f -print | xargs /bin/rm -f
> ```
>
> Find files named core in or below the directory /tmp and delete them.  Note that this **will work incorrectly if there are any filenames containing newlines or spaces.**
>
> ```
>  find /tmp -name core -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f
> ```
>
> Find files named core in or below the directory /tmp and delete them, processing filenames in such a way that file or directory names containing spaces or newlines are correctly handled.

If a file has a name with spaces, say `my vacation in thai.jpg`, what `xargs` does by default is to split it at spaces and invoke multiple `rm`:

```
rm my
rm vacation
rm in
rm thai.jpg
```

You need to make `awk` print null-terminated strings and use `xargs -0` to consume them. In this question: [How can I output null-terminated strings in Awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133315/how-can-i-output-null-terminated-strings-in-awk) it is suggested to use this line:

```
  awk '{printf "%s\0", $0}'
```